# jquery touch navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

The code below adds touch navigation for android/ipads etc. It adds swiping navigation to the slide thumbnails. This works great and all, but the thumbnails are not clickable on a tablet via touch. You can click them on a pc and the slider will change to the appropriate slide...not on a tablet, its as if touching or "clicking" does nothing (the swiping works fine)

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VM8XG/5165/

JS

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({

navigationSize : 3,

// Callback when the plugin finished initializing
onInitialized: function(e, slider) {

    var time = 1000, // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
        range = 50,  // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the slider
        x = 0, t = 0, touch = "ontouchend" in document,
        st = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
        mv = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
        en = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

    slider.$window.add( slider.$controls )
        .bind(st, function(e){
            // prevent image drag (Firefox)
            e.preventDefault();
            t = (new Date()).getTime();
            x = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX; 
        })
        .bind(en, function(e){
            t = 0; x = 0;
        })
        .bind(mv, function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var newx = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
            r = (x === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(newx - x),
            // allow if movement < 1 sec
            ct = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (t !== 0 && ct - t < time && r > range) {
                if (newx < x) { 
                    if ($(this).hasClass('anythingControls')) {
                        slider.$controls.find('.next').trigger('click');
                    } else {
                        slider.goForward();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if (newx > x) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('anythingControls')) {
                        slider.$controls.find('.prev').trigger('click');
                    } else {
                        slider.goBack(); 
                    }
                }
                t = 0; x = 0;
                return false;
            }
        });
}

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the hover event - if you tap on the number tabs twice quickly (may require multiple jabs to catch it!) on an iPad it does successfully navigate to the image.

Can't speak for android but I've noticed that iPad does do hover effects on first click so it may be worth just looking through the script for the image slider, finding out which mouse events it is hooking on to (mouseover, hover etc) and unbind them at the end of your scipt where a tablet is detected.

Answer (score 0):

The `event.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an element from happening.

But you just removed two actions:

```
e.preventDefault();
```